# How do you retrieve values from a soap response

Tags: python, xml, soap

i'm setting up a my program for use of a API, I recently just managed to get the program to send a request to the server and receive a response successfully, however I am unable to make use of the response, may i know how does it work?

I have tried to retrieve values from the response directly from within the python file and as well as having them on two separate files in two different locations however it failed both ways.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    def sendRequest():
        request =""" 

        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://website">
         <soapenv:Header/>
         <soapenv:Body>
              <eter:test1>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <eter:_user>luac</eter:_user>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <eter:_pwd>124</eter:_pwd>
              </object>
         </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>"""
    #encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')
        headers = {"Host": "172.54.21.14",
               "Content-Type": "text/xml",
               "Content-Length": "length"}

        response = requests.post(url="http:/website\?",
                             headers = headers,
                             data = request)
        print (response.text)
        print (response.status_code)
        with open("testSave.xml", "w") as f:
            f.write(response.text)

    def getValue():
        tree = ET.parse('testSave.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        print (root.tag)
        print (root.attrib)
        for mdv in root:
            print (mdv)

    sendRequest()
    getValue()
```

expected the put come to be able to display variables and their values.

actual output is a nameError at `tree = ET.parse('testSave.xml')`

This is the response xml I am trying to use

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAvailableMetadeviceListResponse xmlns="http://www.etere.eu/EtereWSApi"><GetAvailableMetadeviceListResult><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WSApiResponse>

<Function Name="MD_GetAvailableMetadeviceList">

<mdv id_metadevice="3" description="LOWRES"/><mdv id_metadevice="16" description="ETX-G"/><mdv id_metadevice="18" description="subs"/><mdv id_metadevice="23" description="ARCHIVE"/><mdv id_metadevice="32" description="System Storage"/>

</Function>

</WSApiResponse>

</GetAvailableMetadeviceListResult></GetAvailableMetadeviceListResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why dont you use a SOAP client like https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/? Add to the post the xml data that you get as a response.

Comment: i'm trying to do it with as little external help as possible, just pure python would be best if such a solution is available

Comment: Share the response xml

Comment: @balderman edited to include response xml!

Comment: Replace the &lt and & gt with the proper xml chars

Comment: @balderman replaced them but it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the data you are looking for is inside `<Function></Function>` ?

Comment: yes it is in `<Function></Function>`

Comment: OK. Answer was posted

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ''' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAvailableMetadeviceListResponse xmlns="http://www.etere.eu/EtereWSApi"><GetAvailableMetadeviceListResult>

<WSApiResponse>

<Function Name="MD_GetAvailableMetadeviceList">

    <mdv id_metadevice="3" description="LOWRES"/>
    <mdv id_metadevice="16" description="ETX-G"/>
    <mdv id_metadevice="18" description="subs"/>
    <mdv id_metadevice="23" description="ARCHIVE"/>
    <mdv id_metadevice="32" description="System Storage"/>

</Function>

</WSApiResponse>

</GetAvailableMetadeviceListResult></GetAvailableMetadeviceListResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>


'''
#
# Assuming all we care about is under <Function>
#
start_idx = xml.index('<Function')
end_idx = xml.index('</Function>')
xml = xml[start_idx:end_idx + 11]
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
mdv_list = root.findall('.//mdv')
for mdv in mdv_list:
    print('{} --> {}'.format(mdv.attrib.get('id_metadevice'),mdv.attrib.get('description')))
```

output

```
3 --> LOWRES
16 --> ETX-G
18 --> subs
23 --> ARCHIVE
32 --> System Storage
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to avoid putting it in the same file as the xml? because my xml is going to be changing alot ....or is there a way to just change what is in the xml part of the file? hmmmm

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Glad I managed to help. Feel free to vote up.

Comment: I will be using several different xml file/codes, therefore i would to be able to retrieve values for different xml files, if i were to do that the method to retrieve is unable to be in the same file as the xml codes. therefore i would like to look for a method that doesn't require the retrieving code being in the same file as the xml

Comment: If the <Function> is in every response it looks like my code will work for every use case you have. Isnt it?

Comment: yes, so the code you gave should be in the main python file and not the xml file? sorry, because you put the two together so i sort of assumed the reply would be in the same python file as the code given

Comment: The XML is in the code just for the example! They should be separated.

Comment: OH, MY GOD, okok, but the import for the `elementree` and the `xml= '''` is meant to be in the xml?

Comment: May I ask how would xml.index work? xml would be the file.xml? because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `start_idx = xml.index('<Function')`

it gives this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testRequest.py", line 44, in <module>
    start_idx = xml.index('<Function')
NameError: name 'xml' is not defined`

i left it as xml as i'm not sure what should go in there

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("testSave.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.write(response.text)

with open("testSave.txt", "r+") as f:
    content= f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(content.replace('&lt;','<'))

with open("testSave.txt", "r+") as f:
    content= f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(content.replace('&gt;','>'))


with open('testSave.txt', 'r') as f2:
    data= f2.read()
    print(data)
    start_idx = data.index('<Function')
    end_idx = data.index('</Function>')
    data = data[start_idx:end_idx + 11]
    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    mdv_list = root.findall('.//mdv')
    for mdv in mdv_list:
        print('{} --> {}'.format(mdv.attrib.get('id_metadevice'),mdv.attrib.get('description')))
```

i found the solution, this allows me to write the response, change all the '&lt ;' and '&gt ;' to '<' and '>' and then using the code provided by @balderman, extract the data required! thank you!